# За что закрыли мой вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Я не согласен с закрытием моего вопроса: [Error: The N-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports N-API version(s) 3. This Node instance cannot run this module](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246902/error-the-n-api-version-of-this-node-instance-is-1-this-module-supports-n-api)

Он не требует уточнения и в нем есть все для воспроизведения. Прошу переоткрыть!

Comment: Представь, что ты со стороны пришел, посмотри на текст вопроса - указаны версии npm/node, указано что ты установил пакет sqlite3 (не указано какой версии), в заголовке указана ошибка. Что ты делаешь, чтобы получить эту ошибку - неизвестно. Если ты уточнял это в комментариях, то необходимо всю нужную информацию перенести непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: Правильно закрыли, вопрос не содержит описания, откуда взялась эта ошибка

Comment: Скорее нужно было поставить вопрос иначе: ни за что закрыли мой вопрос, а по какой причине.

Comment: закрыт за слишком длинный и нечитаемый заголовок и отсутствие текста.

Answer (score 2):

У вашего вопроса достаточно скудное наполнение. К тому же его невозможно понять не прочитав как заголовок, так и само тело сообщения. Заголовок должен быть достаточно кратким, но если текст основного сообщения без него не ясен, то стоит как минимум продублировать ошибку из заголовка в самом сообщении.

Просто внесите чуть больше подробностей в сообщение и сделайте его самодостаточным (чтобы заголовок был неважен), и тогда, я верю, что его действительно можно будет перееоткрыть.